# Dconf. Can't see "unity panel "

Tags: unity, dconf

In Unity section there are "lenses" and "runner" only.
What should I do to enable "panel"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which Unity section? There are at least few.
I suppose that you need com.canonical.unity.panel to edit whitelist. Interesting thing is that "lenses" and "runner" are in desktop.unity so I can be wrong.

Anyway if I'm right, you use Ubuntu 13.04 and you're looking for com.canonical.unity.panel - it was deleted. You can get it back again by upgrading with "timekiller" repositories added.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:timekiller/unity-systrayfix 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It's from http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/how-to-get-systray-whitelist-back-in.html .

Answer (score 2):

Dconf is quite different from gconf in that it doesn't replicate the entire tree - so if you're using dconf-editor, then there's a really good chance that you won't find what you're looking for.

From what I've been able to figure out, dconf is really just a storage mechanism for your own settings but there's more going on in terms of gsettings. I could be completely wrong (though it's the explanation that's kind of working for me at the moment).

If you want to see the schema, use:

```
gsettings list-schemas
```

Do a search using grep:

```
gsettings list-schemas | grep '\.Unity\.'
```

Once you've got the schema you want, you can then find the keys:

```
gsettings list-keys com.canonical.Uniity.panel
```

Which should give you something like:

> systray-whitelist

To see the value of that key:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Uniity.panel systray-whitelist
```

which returns something like:

> ['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'Update-notifier', 'desura']

To set a value, (say I wanted to add Wicd), it'd be:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'Update-notifier', 'desura', 'Wicd']"
```

Hope that's helpful...